# How to promptly clear Safari's video requests for Blob?

Tags: javascript

In Safari browser, frequent setting of Blob to the video's srcObject may lead to the accumulation of loadedmetadata time due to browser caching mechanism (which doesn't occur in private mode). How can the browser be prompted to clear Blob cache promptly?

I have tried something similar to URL.revokeObjectURL, but it didn't work. Only after manually clearing browser data in the phone settings did the loadedmetadata time for the video return to normal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.